# Getting missing locale error with react-intl

Tags: reactjs, localization, react-intl

I am using react-intl to format date and when setting locale to Bosnia and Herzegovina I get the error
`[React Intl] Missing locale data for locale: "ba". Using default locale: "en" as fallback.`
but in the code i found `ba: ['b','hB']` which is a config for formatting.
How can it be missing ?